# How to style definition list with CSS to create single paragraph with hanging indent for each entry?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Pandoc to turn LaTeX into HTML. It translates LaTeX `description` environments into HTML definitions lists like this:

```
<dl>
<dt>term:</dt>
<dd><p>definition may be very long and, when viewed online, span multiple lines</p></dd>
</dl>
```

The standard appearance is:

```
term:
    definition may be very long and, when viewed
    online, span multiple lines
```

I would like to get:

```
term: definition may be very long and, when viewed
  online, span multiple lines
```

I.e., have the term and definition appear as a single paragraph with hanging indent. What CSS do I need to achieve this? (I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 at the moment, so something that layers nicely on top of that would be particularly welcome, as would something that sets the term in bold.)

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick. (Edited to clear lines and add spacing between items)

```
<section class="latex-list">
  <dl>
    <dt>term:</dt>
      <dd><p>definition may be very long and, when viewed online, span multiple lines</p></dd>
    <dt>term:</dt>
      <dd><p>definition may be very long and, when viewed online, span multiple lines</p></dd>
    <dt>term:</dt>
      <dd><p>definition may be very long and, when viewed online, span multiple lines</p></dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

The style on the `<p>` would cause issues elsewhere so you'll want to have this name scoped to class. You can change `latex-list` to anything you want, but I was assuming you couldn't put it on the lists themselves.

```
.latex-list dl {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.latex-list dt {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
}

.latex-list dd::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
}

.latex-list dd,
.latex-list p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.latex-list dt {
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Might not work for lengthy text(2 or more lines)  in small screen

Answer (score 0):

Using "display: inline" property on the items that have to be placed next to each other

```
dt, dd, p {
  display: inline;
}
```

Refer: https://codepen.io/sprushika/pen/NYZeVb

Comment: Unfortunately I can't easily modify Pandoc's output to inject the `<span>` inside the `<dt>`.

Comment: Also, it appears that your solution changes all `span` elements, not just that in the `dt`? And that the definition body (in `dd`) doesn't have a hanging indent?

Comment: You can use custom class, only to apply this particular dl, say 
.custom-class dl {}, updated the pen, please check again

Comment: Thanks Spushika - that does run them together, but there's no hanging indent (i.e., the wrapped line is flush with the left margin). Unfortunately, I have to have at least a couple of characters' worth of hanging indent.

Comment: Updated! check the pen again :)

Comment: Did you check this one too @GregWilson?